# Garbage output of my int** in a struct being printed

Tags: c, structure, c99

I read integer values from a file, parsing them by the space character, then insert them into a int** that is in my structure called game. Using print statements, I have confirm the correct values are being placed in the int** in the correct position, but once I leave the while loop or return the struct, the values being printed are wrong.

My structure:

```
typedef struct Map_s{

        char * defender;
        char * attacker;
        int missles;
        int ** layout;
        size_t capacity;
        size_t size;
}map;
```

Initialization of the struct:

```
map * newGame(){

        map * game = malloc(sizeof(map));
        game->layout = (int**)malloc(_DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE * sizeof(int*));
        game->defender = NULL;
        game->attacker = NULL;
        game->missles = 0;
        game->capacity = _DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
        game->size = 0;

        return game;
}
```

File parsing:

```
map * game = newGame();

    char * token;
    char * dup;
    char * ptr;
    int ret;
    const char delim[2] = " ";
    char * buf = NULL;
    char * temp = NULL;
    size_t size = _MAX_SIZE;
    int lineNum = 1;

    while( getline(&temp, &size, fp) > 1 ){
            buf = strtok(temp, "\n");
            dup = strdup(buf);
            if( buf[0] != '#' ){
                    if( lineNum == 1){
                            if( game->defender == NULL ){
                                    game->defender = dup;
                            }
                    }
                    else if( lineNum == 2 ){
                            if( game->attacker == NULL )
                                    game->attacker = dup;
                    }
                    else if( lineNum == 3 ){
                            game->missles = atoi(dup);
                    }
                    else if( lineNum > 3 ){
                            token = strtok(dup, delim);
                            while( token != NULL ){
                                    if( game->size >= game->capacity ){
                                            game->layout = (int**)realloc(game->layout, \
                                                            game->capacity*2 * sizeof(int*));
                                            game->capacity = game->capacity * 2;
                                    }
                                    ret = (int)strtol(token, &ptr, 10);
                                    game->layout[game->size] = &ret;
                                    game->size = game->size + 1;
                                    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                    //printf("%s ", token);
                            }
                    }**

                    lineNum++;
            }
    }



    return game;
```

I'm almost positive that my code is messing up somewhere in the second while loop. I am trying to convert the string into an integer and then save it into the correct spot in the int**.

How I am printing from main:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < thisgame->size; i++ ){
            printf("%d ", *thisgame->layout[i]);
            if( i == 0)
                    continue;
            else if( (i+1) % 10 == 0 )
                    printf("\n");
    }
```

Output from main function after returning struct:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

What output should look like (what's in the file):

```
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 6 6 7 7 7 5 5 2
2 2 7 7 7 2 2 17 17 17 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
8 8 8 6 6 6 9 9 9 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
10 10 10 4 4 9 9 9 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 6 6 6 9 9 9 2
3 3 3 6 6 6 9 9 9 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: `game->layout[game->size] = &ret;` You seem to be storing the address of `ret` instead of the value. Is that what you want?

Comment: @D.Go Without the &ret, I am given a warning: makes pointer from integer without cast

Comment: The line `**token = strtok(dup, delim);` ... Is that the actual line of code, or are you using the initial `**` to mark the line? Because that looks to be tryint to double-dereference a pointer that hasn't (at the point of first use) been initialized). Which probably also ruins the first iteration of that loop.

Comment: @PhilM sorry, that was not suppose to be there in the first place. Not sure how it got in there.

Comment: @Boballendo Okay then that should be a clue that this part of your code is incorrect. I don't think you are trying to store an array of pointers, which is how you have this set up. You want an array of ints.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As described that that link, it should be a single piece of source code that can be compiled and run with no modifications and demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an array of *int** when what you really want is an array of *int*. Each time you store `ret`, you're storing the same address. When you check the value in the loop, it will be correct because `ret` contains the value you want... until the next iteration.

Comment: Thank you! Very stupid mistake on my part costing me hours of screen time. Never forget the basics.

Comment: @Boballendo Please do accept one of the answers, so that we know your question is closed. And also, marking them as useful (the up arrow) would be appreciated.

Comment: I did upvote your answer, but because I am new, my answer is recorded and does not publicly display the the score

Comment: @Boballendo Ah, okay. Does it let you accept an answer?

Comment: How do I do that? I do not see anything on the page

Comment: @Boballendo You should see a checkmark under the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues I see.

First is the line `**token = strtok(dup, delim);`. At the first run of this line, `token` has no valid value, and thus dereferencing it not once, but twice, will also cause issues. I believe this should just be `token = strtok(dup, delim);`

This will cause the first iteration of the while loop in that if block to return bad values (all those 0s seem to fit this guess, at least).

Second is what D Go pointed out, in that you are giving the address of `ret` (which address does not change), so that every element of `game->layout` has the same address, and thus looks at the same int (fitting all those 10s).

I think the fix for that would just be to make `layout` an array of `int *` (tweaking the allocation code to fit), and assign `ret` directly to each element.